# How do I launch a new form in front of my original form in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a C# Windows Forms app in Visual Studio 2022. I've added a button on Form1 (form displayed on launch), call it the addWorkersButton.

```
private void addWorkersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExternalDeptEmployeeForm f2 = new ExternalDeptEmployeeForm();
        f2.Show();   
        f2.BringToFront();
    }
```

However, I'm still getting the form launched from the button click to appear behind Form1. I've tried out combinations of several of the available methods to try and achieve this to no avail:

```
private void addWorkersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExternalDeptEmployeeForm f2 = new ExternalDeptEmployeeForm();
        f2.Show();
        this.SentToBack();  
    }
```

From other posts I have found, these examples provided appear to work in a lot of instances, so I'm just not sure what is different in my project that would be preventing this.

I've also attempted to add the newly instantiated form f2 to be owned by the original form (Form1) and then Show() it. I did this because according to the docs, Microsoft says about the AddOwnedForm() method: "Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form." You can find this under **Remarks** here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.addownedform?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

In my Program.cs file, in the Main() method, I am running an instance of Form1, which then appears to require an instance of Form1 to exist during runtime in order for the application to continue to run:

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

If this is an issue, what is the work-around? To me, it seems that there should be no issue displaying f2 in from of Form1, because I am not trying to close it or end that process in any way. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You pass the current instance of form1 to the show method of form2 like: _f2.Show(this);_ Now the current instance of Form1 owns the current instance of Form2 (f2)

Comment: @Steve Thank you, this worked. So, I was missing adding in that parameter to the overloaded Show() method. It seems to make sense though, that parameter is expecting the name of the owner which owns the instance of the form we are performing this method on, in this case f2. Appreciate that, glad it was simple.

Comment: Instead for the Application.Run method nothing better than the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @Steve Awesome. So, docs say most times to use the Run() method how I used it by passing an instance of a form to the parameter. However, they do say for some projects I may need to pass an ApplicationContext to the Run() method instead for "better control over the lifetime of the application".

So, your ApplicationContext can have as many forms as you'd need hypothetically, and then once all of them are closed, then the application would cease running. Is this what is meant by "more control" over the application, or is there more to it?

Comment: `Application.Run()` always starts the Message Loop based on an ApplicationContext. If you pass a Form instance to `Application.Run()`, it creates a default ApplicationContext, so you have default behavior. If you pass your own class derived from ApplicationContext, you can create custom behavior (e.g., you don't call `ExitThread()` when the `[ApplicationContext].MainForm` closes, etc.). You can of course have multiple Forms in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
f2.Show(this);
```

Instead of calling [Control.Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), (i.e. `f2.Show()` with no arguments), you should call [Form.Show(IWin32Window)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and pass the owning window/form as the argument (i.e. `f2.Show(this)`) and the `f2` form will be shown in front of `this` form.  Also, `this` form will be the *owner* of the `f2` form.